# Sphinxtrain snapshot in windows 7

Tags: windows, cmusphinx

I have downloaded sphinxbase.tar.gz and sphinxtrain.tar.gz in windows 7 computer. Build with Visual studio 2010. I have installed Activeperl, python 3.3.

In tutorial http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam it says:

**For sphinxtrain snapshot**

```
sphinxtrain -t an4 setup
```

It is possibly for linux systems. How can I run sphinxtrain (snapshot) in windows 7 (64 bit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows support is still being tested. I have a patch like this, but haven't committed it yet. The patch is here:

http://pastebin.com/NQyNQEHx

Running on Windows:

- first of all, open the Visual Studio project SphinxTrain.sln and build it
- copy the following files in bin\Debug or bin\Release:

  - pocketsphinx_batch.exe and pocketsphinx.dll from the pocketsphinx package
  - sphinx_fe.exe and sphinxbase.dll from the sphinxbase package
- from the directory of your training database run:

  - python SPHINX_DIR\SphinxTrain\scripts\sphinxtrain.in -t db_name setup
  - python SPHINX_DIR\SphinxTrain\scripts\sphinxtrain.in run
- note that the script first considers bin/Release and, if that doesn't exist, bin/Debug

At the same time you can use scripts from release with binaries from snapshot, results will not be different.

Comment: this command only prints a message Running the training ,but nothing happens